# How can I open my all apps list in Amazon App Store App?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I am trying to link the button with my all games in amazon app store. I am using following url in order to do so http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android/r&showall
where  is my app package name. But some how instead of opening it in amazon app store it opens that link in browser. Can anyone one help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Amazon Guidelines - https://developer.amazon.com/help/tuabg.html

> For a link that directs to a list of all of your apps within our U.S.
>   store, please:
>
> Use this link structure:
>   [http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=**com.example.package**&showAll=1](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.example.package&showAll=1)
>   Replace the bold portion with the package name of one of your
>   currently LIVE apps in our store.